# STATISTICS_INCREMENTAL in CREATE TABLE

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, statistics, dbproj

This syntax is legitimate as you can see [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.test1
(
  ID int not null,
  SomeDate datetime2(7) not null,
  CONSTRAINT PK_test1 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID, SomeDate) WITH (STATISTICS_INCREMENTAL = ON)
  ON PS(SomeDate)
) ON PS(SomeDate)
go
```

I can run it on SQL Server 2017 without any issues, but Visual Studio is not happy with this script in a DB project. I get this error

> SQL70616: Unsupported index option specified 'StatisticsIncremental' for [dbo].[test1].

I tried to fix this with

```sql
UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.test1 PK_test1 WITH RESAMPLE, INCREMENTAL = ON
```

but no luck, I got

> SQL70001: This statement is not recognized in this context.

EXEC and sp_executesql also not recognized.

Any chance to explain this to DB Project? I afraid automatic deployment will detect this discrepancy between model and DB and would try to rebuild a table on every deployment.

Visual Studio 16.8.1

SQL Server Data Tools 16.0.62010.06180

Edit 1: It raises the same error if I put it in a separate statement.

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.test1
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_test1
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID, SomeDate) 
WITH(STATISTICS_INCREMENTAL = ON)
ON PS(SomeDate)
```

Edit 2: It does work as a clustered unique index. No errors were raised. It would do, but I'd prefer to have it as a constraint.

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX PK_test1 ON dbo.test1(ID, SomeDate)
WITH(STATISTICS_INCREMENTAL = ON)
ON PS_SportsHub(SomeDate)
```

Edit 3: The target platform is Microsoft Azure SQL Database. It makes no difference, I tried SQL Server 2019/2017 as well.

Comment: Does the database project target SQL 2014 or later?

Comment: @RandyinMarin, the target platform is Microsoft Azure SQL Database.

Comment: I don't know if it relates, but on the project database settings, is "Auto create incremental" checked on the Operational tab?

Comment: @RandyinMarin, no, it doesn't relate.

Answer (score 0):

A bug fix in version Visual Studio 16.11.8 was created to address this issue:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS-sqldb-project-unable-to-create-primar/1528961